# Referencing external files

Tags: python

I have defined a class named `App`, but when calling this class in my main.py it tells me that `App` is not defined, meaning it cannot find the class `App`.

**main.py**

```
import pygame, sys, settings
import app_class


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

**app_class**

```
class App:
  def __init__(self):
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.running  = True
    self.loading = 'Loading'
```

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = App(),
NameError: name 'App' is not defined
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Use either:

```py
from app_class import App
App()
```

or:

```py
import app_class
app_class.App()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your import.

Instead of

```
import app_class
```

Do this:

```
from app_class import App
```